# Sagemaker with windows

Tags: docker, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use aws sagemaker with Windows using Docker :
Here is the docker file :

```
# Build an image that can do training and inference in SageMaker
# This is a Python 2 image that uses the nginx, gunicorn, flask stack
# for serving inferences in a stable way.

FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3.5 \
         nginx \
         libgcc-5-dev \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Here we get all python packages.
# There's substantial overlap between scipy and numpy that we eliminate by
# linking them together. Likewise, pip leaves the install caches populated which uses
# a significant amount of space. These optimizations save a fair amount of space in the
# image, which reduces start up time.
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.3/get-pip.py && python3.5 get-pip.py && \
    pip3 install numpy==1.14.3 scipy scikit-learn==0.19.1 xgboost==0.72.1 pandas==0.22.0 flask gevent gunicorn && \
        (cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/.libs; rm *; ln ../../numpy/.libs/* .) && \
        rm -rf /root/.cache

# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

# Set up the program in the image
COPY xgboost /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

My question is should I, since I work under windows 7, change these path : ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the ENV PATH?

That sets the PATH env within the docker container, which uses linux file system (ubuntu:16.04), so you shouldn't have to change anything.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

EDIT:

I reread your question. None of your paths have to change within your Dockerfile, as they are configured for the docker container themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your response, cause I see in this tutorial [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/brewing-up-custom-ml-models-on-aws-sagemaker-e09b64627722)  that   Windows user, and you’re one of those unfortunates to run the outdated Docker toolbox, make sure you use some directory in the C:\Users directory as your project home folder. Otherwise, you’ll run into a very ugly experience of mounting the folder to the container.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, I apologize for the confusion. But I believe the Dockerfile should still build fine without the Windows file system context (C:) because the Dockerfile builds are relative to when you build your image from the Dockerfile. https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/issues/60

If the folder you're copying over, in which case is 'xgboost' is in the same directory as your Dockerfile, and you build your Dockerfile in the same directory I believe it should work.